# Libgdx: Clickable table is not working

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to implement a table with clickable images using libGDX on Android, but it doesn't work. So I tried the following code for a test:

```
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(uiStage);
    commandListTable = new Table(); //grid for UI command list;
    commandListTable.setHeight(UIStageWidth * 1/2);
    commandListTable.setWidth(UIStageWidth * 3.5f);
    CreateButtons();
    commandListTable.setPosition(UIStageWidth * 2 / 9, UIStageHeight * 1 / 15);
    commandListTable.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);

    commandListTable.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            System.out.println("click " + x + ", " + y);
            Gdx.app.log("Clicked", "CLICK");
        }
    });
    uiStage.addActor(commandListTable);
```

However, it still doesn't work, totally no output. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Did you use debug draw to check if the table really has the specified size? If layout is enabled it might resize it.

Comment: Yes I did. All the lines of the table can be correctly drawn now.

Comment: What do you try to say with that? If the debug lines are drawn correctly, you make another mistake, as this example works for me. What does `CreateButtons()` do? Do you add other actors to your stage?

Comment: CreateButtons() creates some images to be filled to the commandListTable. These images are added to the table by calling the .add() function. I try to add these images as an actor to either commandListTable or uiStage but both the cases don't work.

Comment: Problem fixed. The setInputProcessor function should be put in the Screen class.